# Is there a better solution than `v-html` in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-sfc

I have a Vue component. He will show a text array circularly. In the text, some string has a special style. I can use the `v-html` attribute. Is there a better way?

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const data1 = [
  "An approachable, performant and versatile framework for building web user interfaces.",
  "The library for web and native user interfaces",
];

const data2 = [
  "An approachable, <b>performant</b> and versatile framework for building web user interfaces.",
  "The library for web and <b>native</b> user interfaces",
];
</script>

<template>
  <div class="data1">
    <p v-for="(item, index) in data1" :key="index">{{ item }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="data2">
    <p id="data2" v-for="(item, index) in data2" :key="index" v-html="item"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
:deep(.data2 > b) {
  font-weight: 700;
}
</style>
```

Comment: No, there isn't a better way. `v-html` is the correct way to bind html markup to elements. What is wrong with `v-html` and why do you want a better way?

Comment: `v-html` can lead to [XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/)

Comment: There is a plugin called `vue-safe-html`, But I'm not sure if it works really well. [vue-safe-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-safe-html). Hope it helps you!

Comment: <div  :class="data1 ? 'classForData1' : 'defaultClass' "></div>

Comment: IMO, unless the content is user-provided and it is trusted content, the usage of `v-html` is no risk and is perfect. Also if the content is user-provided, there are ways to sanitize the HTML for potential risk management.

Answer (score 1):

Use interpolation for rendering.

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from "vue";
    const data1 = [
      { part1: "An approachable,", part2: "performant", part3: "and versatile framework for building web user interfaces." },
      { part1: "The library for web and", part2: "native", part3:"user interfaces" },
    ];
</script>

<template>
  <div class="data">
    <p v-for="(item, index) in data1" :key="index">
      {{ item.part1 }} <b>{{ item.part2 }}</b> {{ item.part3 }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```